# Laravel Composite Key Validation

Tags: php, laravel, database, validation, laravel-9

I have a table where there is a composite uniqe key.

I want to validate it before creating the record, so the HTTP request won't return with some SQL error(Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry).

I'm using Laravel 9.

The composite unique key is: user_id, work_id, date (basically u can't work on the same stuff multiple times on the same day)
Only the work_id and the date comes from the $request, the user_id comes from auth()->user()->id;

My current code is:

```php
$fields = $request->validate([
   'work_id' => 'required|integer',
   'date' => 'required|date',
]);
```

But somehow I have to add the validation rule, I explained above, but I have no idea how.

I tried:

Googling it but I haven't found anything useful to me.
I've seen a libary which is supposed to solve this, but it was for Laravel 4.

Comment: Check this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: @gábor-stefler you can write custom validation logic... Here is an documentation link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in rule `unique`, to also have a where clause including your `user_id` column.

```
'work_id' => [
    'required',
    'integer',
    Rule::exists('your_table', 'work_id')->where('user_id', $request->user()->id),
];
```

It did not seem like you specified the table naming, replace `your_table`.